# Combining Multiple Excel Files into a Master Workbook with multiple tabs (sheets)

Tags: python, r

I am working on a project, wherein I have 10 different excel workbooks.

I need to combine those 10 workbook into a single workbook (master workbook) with **10 different sheets (tabs)** . Is there any way I can do it in R/Python?

Each of these 10 different excel workbooks generated has only one sheet per workbook. The data in each of these workbooks are different

Thanks

Comment: Post what you've tried. As hint, you could use pandas load_csv...perhaps that does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in R Studio using the package "xlsx".I have take an example of combining 3 excel sheets.You can replicate your code to reading the 10 excels and combining them into a single master workbook.

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library("xlsx")
# Read your excel files and save them into a dataframe in R
data1<-read.xlsx("C:/yourPathToFile/my_excel_1.xlsx", sheetIndex =1, header=TRUE)
data2<-read.xlsx("C:/yourPathToFile/my_excel_2.xlsx", sheetIndex =1, header=TRUE)
data3<-read.xlsx("C:/yourPathToFile/my_excel_3.xlsx", sheetIndex =1, header=TRUE)
xlsx.writeMultipleData("C:/yourPathToSaveFile/my_master_workbook.xlsx",data1,data2,data3)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. It worked. I think writeMultipleData function is not defined in xlsx package (I used write.xlsx )